# Why is Poisson integral harmonic?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, soft-question

I have a question about the poisson integral.

I need to prove this is a harmonic function. On this forum, I already saw an explanation in which the poisson kernel was rewritten als the real part of an holomorphic function, and that I understand, but I don't think that's enough because the poissin integral is the integral of the poisson kernel and not the poisson kernel itself. So I need to prove that the integral of the poisson kernel is the real part of an holomorphic function.

Maybe I can use the holomorphic function of which the real part is the poisson kernel and then switch integral and taking the real part, but then I need that the integral of that holomorphic function is holomorphic and I don't know how to show that. Anyone have an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What can I specify more? Sorry I'm new so I don't really know. I would be very thankful if anyone could help. I'm looking for this for weeks already..

Comment: Take a look at Theorem 11.22 of Axler's MIRA: https://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf .

Comment: The Poisson Kernel is $\operatorname{PK}(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}$. Now apply the Laplace operator $\Delta=\partial_r^2+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r+\frac{1}{r^2}\partial^2_\theta$.

Comment: But we don't need to show the poisson kernel is harmonic, but the integral of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B(0, 1) \subset \mathbb C$ be the unit disk, and let $g: (-\pi, \pi] \times B(0, 1) \to \mathbb C$ be the function
$$ g(t, z) = \frac{e^{it} + z}{e^{it} - z}.$$

The Poisson kernel is the real of part of $g(t, z)$.

Given a real integrable function $f : (-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb R$, the Poisson integral is the real part of the function $F: B(0, 1) \to \mathbb C$ defined by
$$ F(z) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  g(t, z) f(t) dt .$$

You want to prove that the Poisson integral, $\text{Re}(F)$, is harmonic. As you correctly identified, it is enough to prove that $F$ is holomorphic, since the real part of any holomorphic function is a harmonic function.

I'll show you two different methods for proving that $F$ is holomorphic. Both methods illustrate standard techniques that can be applied elsewhere.

---

**Method 1: The power series trick.**

So let's pick some arbitrary $z_0 \in B(0, 1)$, and pick some radius $r > 0$ such that the disk $B(z_0, r)$ is inside $B(0, 1)$. I'll prove that $F$ is holomorphic in $B(z_0, r)$. Since this argument works for all $z_0 \in B(0, 1)$, it will follow that $F$ is holomorphic on the whole of $B(0, 1)$.

On $B(z_0, r)$, we can write
$$ g(t, z) = \frac{e^{it} + z}{e^{it} - z}  = \frac{e^{it} + z}{e^{it} - z_0  } \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z - z_0}{e^{it} - z_0} } = \frac{e^{it} + z}{e^{it} - z_0  }\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left( \frac{z - z_0}{e^{it} - z_0}\right)^n . $$

So
$$ F(z) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) (e^{it} + z)\sum_{n = 0}^\infty  \frac{(z - z_0)^n}{(e^{it} - z_0)^{n+1}} dt .$$

For any fixed $z$, the convergence of the infinite series is *uniform* in $t$. [You can prove this using the Weierstrass $M$-test: if $d$ is the distance from $z_0$ to the closest point on the unit circle, then $\left| \frac{(z - z_0)^n}{(e^{it} - z_0)^{n+1}} \right| \leq \frac {|z - z_0|^n}{d^{n+1}}$, and certainly, $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac {|z - z_0|^n}{d^{n+1}}$ converges.]

We can therefore go ahead and switch the order of the integral and the infinite sum.

[To spell this out: Define $a(t) = f(t) (e^{it} + z)$ and  $b_n(t) = \frac{(z - z_0)^n}{(e^{it} - z_0)^{n+1}}$. I've suppressed the $z$ variable in my notation, since we're concentrating on how these sums and integrals behave for a fixed $z$. Define $M = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |a(t)| dt $, and note that $M$ is finite, since $f$ is integrable by assumption and $(e^{it} + z)$ is bounded for fixed $z$ as $t$ varies. Given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N'$ such that $\left| \sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty}  b_n(t) \right| < \epsilon $ for all $N \geq N'$ and for all $t$ - this is the uniform convergence property that we established in the previous paragraph. So for all $N \geq N'$, we have $ \left| \int_{-\pi}^\pi a(t) \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} b_n(t) dt -  
\sum_{n = 0}^{N} \int_{-\pi}^\pi a(t)  b_n(t) dt \right| < M \epsilon  $. This shows that  the infinite sum $  
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^\pi a(t)  b_n(t) dt$ converges to the limit $\int_{-\pi}^\pi a(t) \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} b_n(t) dt$.]

Anyway, after switching the order of the integral and the sum, we get the expression
$$ F(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n (z - z_0)^n + z \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} b_n (z - z_0)^n,$$
where
$$ a_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{f(t) e^{it}}{(e^{it} - z_0)^{n+1}} dt, \ \ \ \ b_n =  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{f(t) }{(e^{it} - z_0)^{n+1}} dt.$$

The functions $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n (z - z_0)^n $ and $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} b_n (z - z_0)^n$ are *power series* in $z$! Power series are holomorphic. Therefore, $F$ is holomorphic, and we're done.

[Remember, the calculation we've done is only valid for $z \in B(z_0, r)$. So this calculation only shows that $F$ is holomophic on $B(z_0, r)$. However, you can do a similar calculation for *any* $z_0 \in B(0, 1)$. So $F$ is in fact holomorphic on the whole of $B(0, 1)$.]

---

**Method 2: Morera + Fubini**

By Morera's theorem, if you can show that $\oint_{\partial \Delta} F(z) dz = 0$ for any triangular path $\partial \Delta$ inside $B(0, 1)$, then it would follow that $F$ is holomorphic inside $B(0, 1)$.

Viewing $g$ as a function on $C \times \partial \Delta$, where $C = \{ e^{it} : t \in (-\pi, \pi] \}$ is the unit circle, the function $g$ is *continuous*. $C \times \partial \Delta$ is compact, so $g$ is bounded on $C \times \partial \Delta$. Since $f$ is integrable on $C$ and $g$ is bounded on $C \times \partial \Delta$, the product $g(t,z)f(t)$ is integrable on $C \times \partial \Delta$. So by Fubini's theorem, we can switch the order of the two single-variable integrals, giving
$$ \oint_{\partial \Delta} F(z) dz = \oint_{\partial \Delta} \left( \int_{-\pi}^\pi g(t, z) f(t) dt \right) dz = \int_{-\pi}^\pi  \left( \oint_{\partial \Delta} g(t, z) dz\right) f(t) dt .$$

As you correctly observed, $g(t, z)$ is holomorphic in $z$ for fixed $t$. So for any fixed $t$, $\oint_{\partial \Delta} g(t, z) dz = 0$, by Cauchy's theorem.

Hence $\oint_{\partial \Delta} F(z) dz = 0$. Since the triangular path $\partial \Delta$ was arbitrary, we can infer by Morera's theorem that $F$ is holomorphic on $B(0, 1)$.

---

Edit: In light of the OP's comment below, it seems like there is a third method...

**Method 3: Cauchy-Riemann equations, differentiating under the integral**

Write $F(z) = F_{Re}(x, y) + iF_{Im}(x, y)$, and write $g(t, z) = G_{Re}(t, x, y) + i G_{Im}(t, x, y)$.

Pick an arbitrary $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0 \in B(0,1)$, and pick an $r > 0$ such that $B(z_0, 2r) \subset B(0, 1)$. For $h \in (-r, r)$, consider
$$ F_{Re}(x_0 + h, y_0) - F_{Re}(x_0, y_0) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \left( g_{Re}(t, x_0 + h, y_0) - g_{Re}(t, x_0, y_0) \right). $$

By the mean value theorem,
$$ g_{Re}(t, x_0 + h, y_0) - g_{Re}(t, x_0, y_0) = h\frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x_0 + \eta(t, h), y_0),$$
where $\eta(t, h)$ is some number, dependent on $t$ and $h$, lying in interval $(0, h)$.

So
$$
\frac{F_{Re}(x_0 + h, y_0) - F_{Re}(x_0, y_0)}{h} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)
\frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x_0 + \eta(t, h), y_0) dt.
$$

The function $(t, x) \mapsto \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x, y_0)$ is continuous on $[-\pi, \pi] \times [x_0 - r, x_0 + r]$. Furthermore, it is *uniformly continuous* on this same domain, since $[-\pi, \pi] \times [x_0 - r, x_0 + r]$ is compact.

So given an $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$ \left| \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x_0 + \eta(t, h), y_0) - \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x_0, y_0) \right| < \epsilon $$
for all $h \in (-\delta, \delta)$ and for all $t$.

So for all $h \in (-\delta, \delta)$, we have
$$ \left| \frac{F_{Re}(x_0 + h, + iy_0) - F_{Re}(x_0, y_0)}{h} - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x_0, y_0) \right| < \epsilon \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left| f(t) \right| dt.$$

Thus $\frac{\partial F_{Re}}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)$ exists, and is given by
$$ \frac{\partial F_{Re}}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x_0, y_0).$$

Since $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$ is an arbitrary point in $B(0, 1)$, the above formula holds for all $z \in B(0, 1)$. Using the uniform continuity of $\frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x, y)$ on $[-\pi, \pi] \times [x_0 - r, x_0 + r] \times [y_0 - r, y_0 + r]$, we can see that $\frac{\partial F_{Re}}{\partial x}$ is continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$; since $(x_0, y_0)$ is arbitrary, $\frac{\partial F_{Re}}{\partial x}$  is continuous on $B(0, 1)$.

[To spell this out, uniform continuity of $\frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x, y)$ implies that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta$ such that for $t$ and for all $x' + iy' \in B(x_0 + iy_0, \delta)$, we have $\left| \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x', y') - \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x_0, y_0)\right| < \epsilon$. So for all $x' + iy' \in B(x_0 + iy_0, \delta)$, we have $\left| \frac{\partial F_{Re}}{\partial x}(x', y') - \frac{\partial F_{Re}}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)\right| < \epsilon \int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)|dt$. ]

By almost identical arguments, the other partial derivatives of $F$ can be calculated - these partial derivatives exist, are continuous, and have the expressions that you expect. I won't bother writing these out.

For any fixed $t$, the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $g$ say that
$$ \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial x}(t, x_0, y_0) = \frac{\partial g_{Im}}{\partial y}(t, x_0, y_0), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \frac{\partial g_{Re}}{\partial y}(t, x_0, y_0) = - \frac{\partial g_{Im}}{\partial x}(t, x_0, y_0)$$
These equations hold for any $t$.

Plugging these into our expressions for the partial derivatives of the real and imaginary parts of $F$, we find that
$$ \frac{\partial F_{Re}}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0) = \frac{\partial F_{Im}}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \frac{\partial F_{Re}}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0) = - \frac{\partial F_{Im}}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0).$$

Thus all the partial derivatives of $F$ exist, are continuous, and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations everywhere in $B(0, 1)$. So $F$ is holomorphic.

Comment: I'm very grateful. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Is there a way to show that the integral of something holomorphic is holomorphic by using the cauchy riemann equations (sufficient condition for holomorphic)? the only thing you have to prove then is that you can switch integral and derivative, and we have seen that's allowed if there is a majorant function (independent of z) for the derivative. Is that here the case that we can find a majorant for |d/dz of the poisson kernel|?

Comment: That's a lovely idea. Let me see if I can write this up rigorously...

Comment: Thanks! I think:
|d/dz (1-|z|^2)/(|e^{it}-z|^2) | = |e^{it}|/|e^{it}-z|^2 <= 1/(1-|z|)^2 but then I'm stuck

Comment: I'm also typing by the way. Will take 15 minutes or so...

Comment: Thank you! Very kind

Comment: Sorry, @Kenny Wong, but I don't understand (in the beginning of your explanation) the part "the Poisson integral is the real part of the function..", because f may be complex

Comment: or maybe we can split then f into its real and imaginary part

Comment: If $f$ is complex, then you're right - you should split $f$ into its real and imaginary parts, and apply these arguments separately for the real and imaginary parts of $f$.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sorry little question, why "and certainly, ... converges" holds? (in the first method)

Comment: It's a geometric series! $r =|z-z_0|/d$ is a positive number less than $1$. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ converges to $1/(1-r)$

Comment: Are we sure it's less than 1?

Comment: Yes we are. By assumption, $z \in B(z_0, r)$. (Sorry, that's a different $r$!) So $|z - z_0| < r$. Now $d$ is the distance from $z_0$ to the closest point on the unit circle; meanwhile, $B(z_0, r)$ lies inside the unit disk; therefore, $r \leq d$. Thus $|z - z_0| < r \leq d$. So $|z - z_0| / d < 1$.

Comment: Big thank you!!

Comment: Why is g(t,z)f(t) holomorphic? Maybe a stupid question..

Comment: For a **fixed** $t$, the function $z \mapsto g(t, z) f(t)$ is holomorphic, because it is a product of the holomorphic function $z \mapsto g(t, z)$ and the constant function $z \mapsto f(t)$.

Comment: Thanks you. And g(t,z) is holomorphic because it's a quotient of two holomorphic functions?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

You can show for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ that the Poisson integrals are given by $$P_r*f(\theta)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(k)r^{|k|}e^{2\pi i k\theta}.$$ Writing $z=re^{2\pi i\theta},\,0\leq\theta<1$ the right-hand series becomes $$\sum_{k\geq0}\hat{f}(k)z^k+\sum_{k<0}\hat{f}(k)\bar{z}^{-k}=\hat{f}(0)+\sum_{k>0}\hat{f}(k)z^k+\overline{\sum_{k>0}\overline{\hat{f}(-k)}z^k}.$$
Now $\{\hat{f}(k)\}_k$ is a bounded sequence (Riemann--Lebesgue) and so $\sum_{k>0}\hat{f}(k)z^k$ defines a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{D}$ (from the uniform convergence on compact subsets).
Observing that $\overline{\hat{f}(-k)}=\hat{f}(k)$ shows that $P_r*f$ is the real part of a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$, hence harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$.